# Unable to read strings passed to python from a json file (Has to be an integer)

Tags: python, json

I need to see whether a name is in a json file. Here is my code:

```
playerName = input("Player name: ")
data = json.loads('assets/players.json')

for i in data:
    print(i)
    if i['name'] == playerName:
        #game.game()
```

I am getting an error from line 19 (*if i['name'] == playerName:*) saying **TypeError: string indices must be integers**.

My JSON file is just

```
{
  "name": "hi",
  "details": {
    "credits": 10
  }
}
```

P.S. I have looked on countless posts trying to find solutions but I don't have much experience with JSON in Python.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, it's just I cannot find a way to get my own code to work.
Also, English isn't my first language so sorry for my bad grammar.

Comment: What's unclear? i ===  'name' i[0] === 'n', typeof i === 'string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
for i in data:
```

Is the same as this:

```
for i in data.keys():
```

Now you see that the variable `i` is a *key* of the dictionary, and happens to be a `string`. So you can't index on it using another string. But really, why iterate over the keys, if you already *know* the name of the one you're interested in? you can delete the whole loop! I think you meant to do this instead:

```
if data['name'] == playerName:
```

Comment: it's much better to use `.items()`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no need to iterate over the items, OP already knows which key to use.

Comment: using key access on the whole dict is less performant. key access is made for _random_ accesses.

Comment: I'm now getting an error saying **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'**. I'm not sure if it's just me being thick or what...

Comment: Just use the last line in my answer, that's all there's to it. You don't need to loop over the dictionary!

Comment: Sorry, completely rewriting this comment. I removed *.keys()* and now it's saying **TypeError: string indices must be integers**. Once again, for line 19.

Comment: No, there is no difference. Try running everything from scratch, maybe the variable got reassigned. You just need these lines: `playerName = input("Player name: ")`, `data = json.loads('assets/players.json')`, `if data['name'] == playerName:`

Comment: I seem to be getting an error for everything. I've done exactly that and now I have an error saying **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**. By the way, I really appreciate your help. Also, do you know if the JSON file may be the problem?

Comment: Well, it seems that the program can't find the file anymore. Check everything, make sure it's there, start from scratch. It's something specific to your environment, because the code should work.

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Once again I seriously appreciate all the help. Take care friend.